# ObservableCollection not updating ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection

i know, there are many questions like this, but i can't get it to work ...

I've a ObservableCollection with a string, an bool. The ListView is bound to that and has a CheckBox and a TextBox. Now i need to check an item via code ... when i change the bool-value, nothing appears in the GUI.

When i check the ListView item, the collection gets updated.

**ObservableCollections**

```
public ObservableCollection<MvItems> Mailverteiler { get { return _Mailverteiler; } }
public ObservableCollection<MvItems> _Mailverteiler = new ObservableCollection<MvItems>();

public class MvItems
{
  public string MvName { get; set; }
  public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

**How to "check" an item:**

```
foreach (MvItems mvitem in Mailverteiler)
{
  mvitem.IsChecked = false;
  if (mvitem.MvName.ToString().Contains(tblFirma.Text))
  {
    mvitem.IsChecked = true;
  }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView x:Name="lvMailverteiler" Margin="20,10,20,0" FontSize="9" SelectionMode="Extended" Height="260" ItemsSource="{Binding Mailverteiler}">    
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="280" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="230" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding MvName}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**How to add items:**

```
this.lvMailverteiler.ItemsSource = Mailverteiler;
_Mailverteiler.Add(new MvItems { MvName = group.DisplayName, IsChecked=false });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thing is, `ObservableCollection` raises the `CollectionChanged` event when an item is added/deleted/moved. 
But it doesn't raise the `PropertyChanged` event when the property of one of its items is updated.

You need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event on the property setters of your `MvItems` class.

For example:

```
public class MvItems : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void  RaisePropertyChanged(
            [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]
            string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string mvName;
    public string MvName
    {
        get => return mvName; 
        set
        {
            mvName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => return isChecked; 
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

---

*EDIT: you will find many examples on how to raise Propertychanged event in a setter on internet. 
On a side note, I prefer to use [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) that automatically add the "raising event" line of code in the setters of your classes implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface.*

Comment: You should provide some example implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` just in case.
Though ... this probably is a dupe anyways

Comment: You re right, but there are so many valid syntaxes with the different C# versions... I personally use [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) so that i don't have to write them myself...

Comment: While there may be various compiler additions, actual implementation always remains the same though

Comment: Although, if he starts implementing it by himself, he will not be able to use Auto-Implemented properties anymore. He'll have to add private fields and retrieve/change them from Properties getters/setters

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've seen something like this before ... my problem is, how can i get my bool IsChecked implemented into this class? I'm to this ... always worked with VB.Net and VBA and so on :)

Comment: I edited the example to fit your class `MvItems`. Your class should look like this to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that your GUI is updated when IsChecked changes.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank u very much ... just made the ObservableCollection public and changed `get => return mvName;` to `get { return isChecked; }` and now everything is fine ... Thanks!